# How to build wildcard for boolFilter in ElasticSearch java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using java on elasticsearch server to query data. But problem is how to query this snippets in java enviroment:

```
"must_not": [
        {
            "wildcard": {
            "rawlog.hostname": "*24h*"
                    }
        }
    ],
```

I used:

```
QueryBuilder qb = wildcardQuery("rawlog.hostname", "*24h*");
BoolFilterBuilder boolFilterBuilder = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();
boolFilterBuilder.mustNot(qb);
```

But it's seem not right. Can anyone help me to get around this problem? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct? Have you tried to run it?